# Ensure AND always returns result

Tags: solr

Currently, if I search a set of 107 indexed MLB schedules for HOUSTON BOSTON ATLANTA GOOBER, and no document contains GOOBER, it returns 0 results.

Is there a way to do a search where if one of the terms is not found, then it will return results as if the search was HOUSTON BOSTON ATLANTA (effectively ignoring GOOBER)?

I'm doing this from the Solr Web UI. Nothing fancy.

Followup: If this is not possible, where would I start to implement that capability myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by definition, AND is always going to return true if and only if all conditions are true. You don't want to "ensure AND always returns result" (let's not violate long-standing conventions of boolean logic, eh?), rather, you want to have application logic that will detect if your AND query returns no results. If so, fire off an alternate query. Or better yet, write your boolean phrases so you can do that in one query. (Not always possible, but quite often so.)

Sounds like you need to use OR. For example: `HOUSTON OR BOSTON OR ATLANTA OR GOOBER`. If Goober doesn't exist, anything with Houston, Boston, or Atlanta in it will still be found. On the up side, if something with Goober does exist, Goober will be found as well.

If you're a more specific about your use cases for your query, I might be able to help you further if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! While I've had experience with PHP and PostgreSQL 5 years ago, I'm very new to Solr and Java.

I agree that using the OR will guarantee results, and there will be more results than I need, but will those results will be ranked with the highest match-count first?
I guess if I want to do what I wanted I'd need to search for Houston, take those results and search for Boston, etc.
Then if a subset search returns no results (Goober), keep searching with the previous set.
That could be very time-consuming...

Comment: Documents that have more references to the search term(s) should float closer to the top. What, exactly, are you trying to do? If you expect only a small (< 25) number of records to come from each query, several small queries one after the other isn't so bad. You would want to load test heavily, of course.

Comment: I have a client that wants to implement an AND search that never fails. The example being when it hits a word that is missing (GOOBER), then the search doesn't fail. It simply ignores that word.

My confusion is whether this is application-dependent, or is a new Solr search function made available to developers.

Comment: It sounds like they'd be happy if you just "implemented an AND search that never fails" by using an OR.  If you don't want to use an OR (or can't because of bizarre specs), then you'll have to handle that logic on the application side because Solr doesn't have a feature where it will just default to OR if an AND search fails.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem is, these people don't have a software product. There's no query for me to craft to do searches a certain way. I'm not tasked with making Target's or Home Depot's search more efficient. 

These are basically users who have noticed that certain searches fail. They want me to write a Solr (or maybe even Lucene) function that will satisfy their "AND that never fails" criteria, and sell it to companies to make their life better.

My constant comment to them is that the problem is not Solr, it's how developers craft the search from the terms entered in a search box.

Comment: You may want to look into Solr Plugins. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins The section on RequestHandlers may be of particular interest. SearchComponents as well. I've never had need to write my own plugin, so I can't be much help beyond that.

Comment: I will pursue that avenue. Thanks so much for the help and direction!